# Octave calling a function from another file

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I am new to `octave` and would like  to experiment with an octave-based library for class imbalance learning available [here](https://github.com/chongshengzhang/Multi_Imbalance/tree/master/src/Multi_Imbalance_Octave).

After setting up the environment as described in the [user guide](https://github.com/chongshengzhang/Multi_Imbalance/blob/master/doc/User_manual_Octave.pdf) (pp. 18), to use the algorithm [FuzzyImb](https://github.com/chongshengzhang/Multi_Imbalance/tree/master/src/Multi_Imbalance_Octave/FuzzyImb), one runs:

```
>> [predictions]=fuzzyImbECOC(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest,'w6',0.1);
```

However, every time I run this, I get the error:

It appears [fuzzyImbECOC.m](https://github.com/chongshengzhang/Multi_Imbalance/blob/master/src/Multi_Imbalance_Octave/FuzzyImb/fuzzyImbECOC.m) calls [funECOC.m](https://github.com/chongshengzhang/Multi_Imbalance/blob/master/src/Multi_Imbalance_Octave/FuzzyImb/funECOC.m) at line 24:

```
24    code = funECOC(numberc);
```

Which generates the undefined error.

```
error: 'Pseudo_random_Coding undefined near line 45, column 45
error: called from
       funECOC at line 45 column 9
       fuzzyImbECOC at line 24 column 6
>>
```

I can confirm all files are available in my working directory, and path added to `octave` as described.

Can someone help resolve this problem?

**EDIT**

```
funECOC.mat

45    code=Pseudo_randdom_Coding(N_class,N_dichotomizers,zero_prob);
```

Comment: Where is `Pseudo_randdom_Coding` in that repository? I can't find it

Comment: line 45 of the `funECOC.m` file: https://github.com/chongshengzhang/Multi_Imbalance/blob/master/src/Multi_Imbalance_Octave/FuzzyImb/funECOC.m

Comment: That is where its called, but where is it defined? It does not seem to exist, and therefore the undefined error would make sense

Comment: Ah, I think they called it wrongly, here's how it is defined: https://github.com/chongshengzhang/Multi_Imbalance/blob/master/src/Multi_Imbalance_Octave/FuzzyImb/pseudoRanddomCoding.m

Comment: Yep, they are called wrongly